# Assign an object to an array within a loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I try to fill an array with objects that are created within a loop as follows. The problem is that all cells seem to have the same object in the end. The explanation might be that `obj` is not a local variable with respect to the loop.

```
Sub foo()
    Dim Arr(1 To 3) As Class1
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 3
        Dim obj As New Class1
        obj.name = i
        Set Arr(i) = obj
    Next
    For i = 1 To 3
        Debug.Print Arr(i).name 
    Next
End Sub
```

Surprisingly, the output is

```
3
3
3
```

I have also tried to remove the `Set` and instead have `Arr(i) = obj`. That results in `Object variable or with block variable not set`.

Comment: `Dim Arr(1 To 3) As Class1` The variable must be of Variant data type. `Dim obj As New Class1` You can't set a Dim statement in a loop. I don't know why it doesn't crash. Anyway, you name the same `obj` as `i` three times. The last `I sticks. Of course, ` Set Arr(i) = obj` does assign this same `0bj` to 3 elements of Arr() and, you are right, it's the same object assigned to 3 elements of Arr().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is the declaration of your object.

```vb
Dim foo as New bar
```

That is called a [self-assigned declaration](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/SelfAssignedDeclaration) what makes setting a new object optional. If you call an objects member and it is not allready set it get's created (implicit`Set foo = New bar`). But as you allready created an instance (on first call to`obj.name`). that one is reused and the same reference is stored three times for the same objects-instance. That's why all elements in array return the same value as they are the same objects-instance, not three different ones.

So don't use`New`in declarations, then you always need a`Set foo`and can check the object instance on`Nothing`.

A second issue with your code is that assigninig an object to an array is that deleting elements from an array is error prone and not deleted references lead to not disposed, but unused objects.

The prefered storage for object(-references) is a`Collection`.

```vb
Sub foo()
    Dim ObjCollection as Collection
    Set ObjCollection = New Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 3
        Dim obj As bar
        Set obj = New bar
        obj.name = i
        ObjCollection.Add obj
    Next
    For i = 1 To 3
        Debug.Print ObjCollection(i).name 
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way:-

```
Sub foo()
    Dim Arr(1 To 3) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 3
        Set Arr(i) = Worksheets(i)
    Next
    For i = 1 To 3
        Debug.Print Arr(i).Name
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets` are existing objects. The goal is to create new objects inside the loop. It can be done like this: `Set Arr(i) = New Class1` and `Arr(i).name = i`

Comment: `Set Arr(i) = Worksheets.Add` would create a new object and assign it to the variable. Follow the rules for creating the kind of object you have in mind. Treat Arr(i) as you would treat any other variable to which you assign an object.

Comment: I think if you could point out what is going wrong in my code, your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 ways to do this:

**Notes**: obj has not been recreated, so when you call for the next time obj in Arr (1) is still affected by the subsequent call.

First:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim Arr(2) As Variant

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim obj As New Class1
    For i = 0 To 2
        Set obj = New Class1 '<<<-----
        obj.name = i
        Set Arr(i) = obj
    Next
    For i = 0 To 2
        Debug.Print Arr(i).name
    Next
End Sub
```

Second:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim Arr(2) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 2
        Dim obj As New Class1
        obj.name = i
        Set Arr(i) = obj
        Set obj = Nothing  <<<-----
    Next
    For i = 0 To 2
        Debug.Print Arr(i).name
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it'll save you a lot of headaches. Cheers!

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()    
    Dim Arr(1 To 3) As New Class1 ' < good to know this version
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 3
       With Arr(i) ' < saves you some typing
          .Name = i
          Debug.Print .Name
       End With
    Next
End Sub
```